# Why is hello-world mobile app not working on EU servers

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am using the [world app](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-helloworld.git) from git  and try to connect to my app on UK-EU server but I always got

> AuthorizationProcessManager.handleAuthorizationFailure in
>   AuthorizationProcessManager.java:426 :: authorization process failed

When I create the same app in US region everything works just fine (only
ping is terrible).

Whats wrong with EU servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [bms-samples-android-helloworld github](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-helloworld/tree/master) has been updated to fix this. The root cause was the gradle build file not being set to pull in the latest BMS SDK.

Sorry for the inconvenience, I just confirmed and it should work now.